# Can a for loop have an assignment in its statement?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I came upon this syntax

```
for (string st; getline(is, st, ' '); v.push_back(st)); 
        ^                  ^                  ^
    initialization   condition, increment    ???
```

How does the `v.push_back(st)` work as an increment when that's being covered by `getline(is, st, ' ')`?

Comment: It does not have to be an 'increment', just an operation, any operation. This keeps pushing strings into the vector as long as the condition is met.

Comment: In short, **Yes** it can.

Comment: `v.push_back` is a function call, not an assignment

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's equivalent to:

```
for (string st; getline(is, st, ' '); )
    v.push_back(st);
```

or:

```
{
    string st;
    while (getline(is, st, ' '))
        v.push_back(st);
}
```

The fact is that the *increment statement* is executed at the end of the body of the loop every time the condition is fulfilled. So, you can see it as the very last instruction of the body.

Sometimes, you may leave the increment statement empty; in this case, you put the only instruction of the body in place of the increment statement.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that the increment statement could be anything but the increment statement.

Comment: "in this case, you put the only instruction of the body in place of the increment statement." - You *can* do this, but that may not be a great idea from a coding style point of view.  What if you need to add a second statement?  IMHO the increment should be semantically a "get ready for the next iteration/finish this iteration"-kind of thing, which may or may not be the case here.

Comment: @Kevin You are kicking down an open door! I absolutely agree.

Answer (score 27):

From the [standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for):

```
 for ( init-statement condition(optional) ; iteration_expression(optional) ) statement
```

> iteration_expression  -   any expression, which is executed after every
>   iteration of the loop and before re-evaluating condition. Typically,
>   this is the expression that increments the loop counter

The above syntax produces code equivalent to:

```
{
    init_statement; 
    while ( condition ) { 
        statement;
        iteration_expression; 
    }
}
```

So it doesn't have to be increment.

Comment: Shouldn't be the `init-statement` optional?

Comment: Semicolon was added by mistake on edit, I'll update it. By formal definition it is not optional though, it just may be empty and must end with `;`

Comment: Well, if you use `continue` somewhere in `statement`, your rewrite isn't quite correct. </pedantic>

Comment: @Deduplicator, excellent point! The statement has to be modified in the case of `continue ` being part of it. Haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't increment anything. The for loop terminates when the condition part is not satisfied. So when `getline` returns false, the loop will terminate.

In many cases, the operation is indeed increment a variable, and the condition probably checks if that variable doesn't exceed some limit. Don't let that confuse you, just remember that the `for` loop has the following (general) structure:

```
for (init; condition; operation)
```

Comment: Thank you, always assumed that the `operation` was going to be an incremental statement.

Answer (score 8):

It does *not* have to be an increment expression. What it's expected to do is determined by you. The code is just same as the following semantically.

```
string st;                       // run before the loop and only once
while (getline(is, st, ' ')) {   // condition used to determine the loop should continue or break
    v.push_back(st);             // run every time inside the loop
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer is it doesn't work as an increment.

The for loop will have the same result as the while loop below:

```
string st;
while (getline(is, st, ' '))
{
    v.push_back(st);
}
```

One could argue if the for loop example you gave is a desirable coding style.

Answer (score 5):

> How does the `v.push_back(st)` work as an increment when that's being covered by `getline(is, st, ' ')`?

It doesn't. You've misunderstood (or been mistaught) the `for` loop construct.

Here are its components:

- a statement to be evaluated before the loop begins;
- an expression to be evaluated at the beginning of each iteration, which will be cancelled if the expression converts to boolean `false`;
- a non-declarative statement to be evaluated at the end of each iteration.

That's it.

There is nothing to dictate which (if any!) of these components perform an increment. Consider the common example `for (;;)` … no operations here at all, let alone an increment!

Answer (score 4):

This loop will run while `getline` returns a stream without errors (take a look at [`operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)). On each iteration, the `st` will be pushed into `v`. I'd rewrite this in terms of `while` loop:

```
string st;
while(getline(is, st, ' '))
{
    v.push_back(st)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All that matters is that the final state of the code in the condition block have a value. That value is compared to zero, and if zero, the for loop is not entered. Essentially, in the good old, small program days of telco's using C and Unix, the contents of the Accumulator was evaluated for zero state by examining the 'Z'ero flag after the code in the condition block was executed.

Answer (score 1):

v.push_back(st) is a function that carries out an operation on the 'st' parameter. the operation however, according to your question isn't shown. So we cannot determine if it's of an increment. But then, the syntax is very possible!!!